# Jquery form submit empty values to Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, intel-xdk

My IntelXDK HTML5 mobile app form submitting empty values to the MySQL database.

My HTML (Single file app)

```
<label class="item item-input widget uib_w_6 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="fullname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fullname" name="fullname">
</label>
<label class="item item-input widget uib_w_7 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="email">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
</label>
<label class="item item-input widget uib_w_8 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="pass">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
</label>
<button class="button widget uib_w_9 d-margins button-positive" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" id="signup">
    Create Account
</button>
<span class="uib_shim"></span>
```

My JS

```
$(document).on("click", "#signup", function (evt) {
    /* your code goes here */ 
    //these two lines take the values from inputs using jquery
    var input1 = $("#fullname").val();
    var input2 = $("#email").val();
    var input3 = $("#pass").val();

    //jquery ajax to send values to php using POST
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/signup.php',
        data: {
            fullname: input1,
            email: input2,
            pass: input3
        },
        success: function (response) {
            //from php using echo
            alert(response);
        }
    }); 

    return false;
});
```

And the PHP file

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$fullname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fullname'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$pass = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['pass'])); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO login (fullname, email, pass) VALUES ('$fullname','$email', '$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Upon submitting this form, it is creating empty records in MySQL.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you haven't set the id's of input fields then how getting the value of input fields with id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Fullname" name="fullname">
```

there is no id like id="fullname" available and you are referring to it.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just to note, if label has same ID, still will send empty data. Change label ID or remove it. Then it works fine.